# How to store API in rethinkdb which is coming from ad server

Tags: jquery, rethinkdb, advertisement-server

How to store API in rethinkdb which is coming from ad server and widget. How can I store those in rethinkdb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using JavaScript, you can just insert a JavaScript object into RethinkDB. Just make sure to convert your API response into a JS object.

```
var obj = { type: 'type', property: 'property' };
r.table("api")
 .insert(obj)
 .run(conn, callback)
```

Take a look at the documentation for `insert`.

Keep in mind that you cant' interact with RethinkDB directly from the browser.